# Nginx + PHP-FPM serving .php files as downloads

Tags: centos, php, nginx

It's a matter asked thousand times and since I hate write posts, I read and search for all possible documentation before get to the annoying part (for me) which is writing.

So I have Nginx & PHP-FPM up and running with CentOS 7.2. PHP-FPM is working with `/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock`properly declared in *www.conf*:

```
; The address on which to accept FastCGI requests.
; Valid syntaxes are:
;   'ip.add.re.ss:port'    - to listen on a TCP socket to a specific address on
;                            a specific port;
;   'port'                 - to listen on a TCP socket to all addresses on a
;                            specific port;
;   '/path/to/unix/socket' - to listen on a unix socket.
; Note: This value is mandatory.
listen = /var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock
```

This is my *mywebsite.conf*:

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name  www.mywebsite.net;

    # note that these lines are originally from the "location /" block
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Also I have `cgi.fix_pathinfo=0` in *php.ini*.

I have restarted/reloaded Nginx and PHP-FPM services, restarted the whole server, and got nothing. I can't display .php files, they're just downloads.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are there any other `server` blocks in `Nginx` configuration, especially  with `listen 80 default` or `default_server` directives?
Also try to add `access_log` and `error_log` to `Nginx` configuration to find out are there any access to that server and are there any errors.

Comment: Yes, there's actually another server block:

`server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  _;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        location / {
        }

 error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

 error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }`

Comment: So it means that right now you have to use `www.mywebsite.net` name to access your site with php configured. For all other names even `mywebsite.net` you will access default section and simply download files as is. Simple solution would be remove `default_server` from default server block and use it on your `www.mywebsite.net` server block. But also I recommend you to put all server names here and place files on different document root, so there will be no chance to download source php files with any fake server name.

Answer (score 0):

sudo vim /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf

DO NOT UNCOMMENT listen.mode = 0660

Comment: What are you saying? that the user should open ``/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf`` in an editor, ***but change nothing?***  That doesn’t make any sense.